# Possibility of generalization of Galois extension related to biquadratic Equation.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I know that if $K/F$ is a field extension, then $Gal(K/F)\simeq\mathbb{Z}_2$ if and only if $K=F(\sqrt{D})$ for some square free $D\in F$. And I also know that using the same notation, $Gal(K/F)\simeq\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ if and only if $K=F(\sqrt{D_1},\sqrt{D_2})$ for some square free $D_1,D_2\in F$ and $D_1D_2$ is also square free.
And it seems that this is generally true by Fundamental theorem of Galois theory in particular by degree part: $Gal(K/F)\simeq\mathbb{Z}_2\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ ($n$ times) if and only if $K=F(\sqrt{D_1},...,\sqrt{D_n}$) any element of the form $\Pi D_i$ is square free in $F$.
First of all is it true? And is this statement similarly true for $n$th root form like $\sqrt[n]{D_1},...,\sqrt[n]{D_m}$ including primitive $n$th root of unity or even the form like $\sqrt[n_1]{D_1},...,\sqrt[n_m]{D_m}$ with appropriate primite roots?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer_theory

Comment: Oh, I didn't know such theory exists. Thanks:)

Comment: Nitpick:  The first sentence is incorrect in characteristic two. In characteristic two $K=F(\sqrt{D})$ is an inseparable extension, so it is not Galois.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to type in.